# get the last registrations in a conference

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show some info about the last 2 registrations in a conference in a table like below. This tables shows, for example, that the last registration was did by John and is a registration with 2 participants and the total value of the registration was 10.00.

```
User that did the registration | Quantity of participants registered | Total Value
            John                               2                        10.00$
            Jake                               1                        5.00$
```

Do you know how to properly achieve this with a sql query? Im testing like this but its not working:http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/225d82.

```
select users.name, 
  count(participants.registration_id), 
   sum(registration_types.price) 
from 
  users,
  participants, 
  registration_types
Group by(users.name)
```

The query is returning:

```
name    count(participants.registration_id)     sum(registration_types.price
Jake              8                                          80
John              8                                      80
```

But it should return:

```
name    count(participants.registration_id)     sum(registration_types.price
Jake              3                                     30
John              1                                     10
```

**Tables structure relevant for the question:**

I have the participants table that stores all participants of a conference:

```
id     registration_id      registration_type_id      name        
1        1                        1                   Jake 
2        1                        1                   Jane
3        1                        2                   Paul
4        2                        2                    Ben
```

The registration table stores all the registrations:

```
id       status     conference_id     user_that_did_registration
1         incomplete     1                        1   (User with id 1 did the registration in the conference with id 1)
2         incomplete     1                        2
```

The registration types table stores the registration types:

```
id     name       price         conference_id
1      rtype1      5.00              1
2     rype2        10.00             1
```

The users table

```
id      name       
1       John
2       Jake
```

Comment: Lets focus on your question - get the last two registrations for a conference.
I dont see anything in your query that constrains for the most recent two records. How does your design support filtering on that information?
As mentioned in the answer below, you need to store some datetime information about the registration - the datetime it was taken for example, so that you can filter on that.

Comment: Once you've done that, you need to address the cartesian product in your query. Fix that, and all your sums will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, but if it shows the correct data then its just necessary to use limit and order by. But the initial part of the query that is to get the name of the user that did the registration, the quantity of participants and the total dont shows the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your expected result, you seem to need to do like this.

```
SELECT u.name,COUNT(pp.registration_id),SUM(rt.price) 
FROM registration_types rt 
INNER JOIN participants pp on pp.registration_id = rt.id
INNER JOIN users u on u.id = pp.registration_id
group by u.name
```

sqlfiddle:http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d28adf/8

**[Results]**:

```
| name | COUNT(pp.registration_id) | SUM(rt.price) |
|------|---------------------------|---------------|
| Jake |                         3 |            30 |
| John |                         1 |            10 |
```

**Note:**

- ANSI 92 standard `join` , so use `JOIN` instead of a comma, `,` with `where` condition is an old style of `join`.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain this part "INNER JOIN users u on u.id = pp.registration_id"? Because the registration_id in the participants table is not the user_id.

Comment: Because I guess `registration_id ` means user registered ID

Comment: No, registration_id is the id of the registration, the user id of the user that did the registration is stored in the registrations table in the column "user_that_did_registration" as it is in the fiddle.

Comment: Registrations table: CREATE TABLE registrations
    (`id` int, `status` varchar(10), 
     `user_that_did_registration` int, 
     `conference_id` int,
     `date_created` datetime)
;

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tracking the time/date that the registration was created, you will not be able to retrieve it.

I would suggest doing something along these lines:

`CREATE TABLE registration_types
    (id int, name varchar(3),price double, conference_id int, date_created datetime);`,

and then when you create a registration, you should store the current time.  You should then be able to order by that field when querying the database.  Also, I would recommend joining on an ID when joining the tables.  Currently you are doing a cross join, which is the cartesian product of the tables

`users,
  participants, 
  registration_types`.

This creates meaningless data and takes up more space than is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but with that the query dont shows also the correct data.